# how do I get my file manager app to start a file when clicked Android?

Tags: android

I am working on a basic file manager, and I am having trouble starting a file. I have it so that when you click a folder it opens, but how do I get it to start a file when a file is clicked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For video or audio, you can start the file like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp4");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent); 

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp3");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

and for other types of files, you can get its MIME type through MimeTypeMap (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html).